# $ANDROID_HOME Environment Variable error in cordova [HOW TO SOLVE ISSUE ON LINUX]

Tags: android, linux, cordova, ionic-framework

### **!Disclaimer: I'm a noob in Linux and this is a [bodge](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lIFE7h3m40U).**

I started to develop an app in Ionic and every time I wanted to build my app I ran into this Error:

```
    Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it manually.
    Try to reinstall Android SDK or update your PATH to include a valid path to SDK/tools directory.
```

So, I found a bodge... every time I wanted to build my app, I used

`export ANDROID_HOME=/path/to/android/sdk`

`export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`

`sudo ionic cordova build android`

However, I have learned from experience that sudo, is it's own shell, so the Environmental Variables set by me at the start were obsolete.

The problem is:

> You set your Environmental Variables to your shell
>
> And then you use sudo to build the application.
>
> > But sudo, as I stated before, does not take into consideration our EV set in our shell.

So, the solution I found is to **just build it as root (not sudo, root).**

Why `root` and not `sudo`?

Well, you cannot set EV with `sudo`. Try it (it won't work).

Before you start to build your application, just use
`su` and start a root shell.

If you have other solutions, please let me know.

P.S: Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Did you create the project as root? Because it's the only reason I can imagine why you need root permissions to build the app. Try to change the permissions of the app's directory as normal user, export the env variables and build it as non-root user.

Comment: No, the project was not created as root. But many people use `sudo` when they install the android sdk so, it is installed to the `/root/Android/Sdk` directory , not the `/home/User/Android/Sdk`.